# npm install error: error : spawn ENOENT when trying to build Cordova project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, npm, windows-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I'm having trouble compiling my project, I am beginner with `Cordova`.

Tried in many ways, to install the dependencies separately (maybe not knife sense), but also tried to change the environment variables (ex: C:\apache-ant-1.9.3 ...).

I also tried to reinstall ("vs-mda and vs-mda-targets").

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Tools for Apache Cordova.

[image]

**Image with all errors:** [enter link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aeXo.png)

Comment: That error indicates a file or directory was not found.  Set the build output to diagnostic (Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project build output verbosity) and do a clean build. That may provide more useful information about the failure. You can post the relevant failure information from the build output to get recommendations on how to fix the issue.  Are you using CTP3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found a solution to the visual 2013. However encontrie the solution . I changed my machine , and installed visual studio 2015 Which has the Cordova, everything worked Correctly .

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this error prop up when the npm cache is set to %ProgramFiles% which requires admin privileges. If thats the case, set it to a location within %appdata%.

```
npm config get cache --> find out the current cache location. 
npm config set cache %APPDATA%\npm-cache --> set the cache location
```

You can also have the same issue with npm prefix. To fix that, here are the set of commands

```
npm config get prefix 
npm config set prefix %APPDATA%\npm
```

Comment: my cache is  "c:\users\myuser\AppData\roaming\npm-cache"
prefix is "c:\users\myuser\AppData\roaming\npm"

Comment: But thanks for help! i want only hello world on cordova:( rsrsr